# how to mock methods of my superclass using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am facing issues in mocking the data for the methods which are being called without the reference e.g getMethod(); don't know how will mocking framework know about it. Below is the code for which am facing issue am not able to set HttpRequest and URIInfo in my code.

Is it possible to bypass the method.

```
Class A {

private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
private UriInfo uriInfo;

public HttpServletRequest getReq() {
    return httpRequest;
}
public void setReq(HttpServletRequest req) {
    this.httpRequest = req;
}


public UriInfo getUriInfo() {
    return uriInfo;
}
public void setUriInfo(UriInfo uriInfo) {
    this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
}}



class B extends A {

// some code

}

class C extends B {

protected Object executeCall(Object beIn) throws Exception{

prepareUpdateConfigurationRequest();
// some other methods.
return "";
}
private void prepareUpdateConfigurationRequest() {
implPutCustomerProductOrderIdProductConfigurationsImpl.setReq(getReq());
implPutCustomerProductOrderIdProductConfigurationsImpl.setUriInfo(getUriInfo());
}}
```

// Test class using Mockito Framework

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CTest {

@Mock
private A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
@InjectMocks
private C c = new C();

private ImplBackEndInput implBackEndInput;

@Test
public void testExecuteCallObject() {



    implBackEndInput = new ImplBackEndInput();

    UriInfo uriInfo = Mockito.mock(UriInfo.class);

    Mockito.when(a.getUriInfo()).thenReturn(uriInfo);
    Mockito.when(a.getReq()).thenReturn(httpServletRequest);

    try {
        c.executeCall(implBackEndInput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
}
```

Comment: How do you call `executeCall` from the test class with its visibility being `protected`?

Comment: @InjectMocks
private C c = new C();

Comment: Can you try to add this following line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Protected or privates methods cannot be mocked using Mockito, I would suggest if you are using spring to you create a DummyC class in your test package, reference that as a parent in the springConfig and make it just return the object when is called. In that way the class will use that method as a by-pass to the real class that you don't need to test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how your code is compiling, given some static references to non-static methods - `A.getUriInfo()` - and various other errors. It also doesn't make a whole lot of sense that you're calling setters using getters for the same object:

```
implPutCustomerProductOrderIdProductConfigurationsImpl.setReq(getReq());
implPutCustomerProductOrderIdProductConfigurationsImpl.setUriInfo(getUriInfo());
```

But to answer your question for anyone else who might wind up here, you don't need to be mocking type A in the test class at all (here):

```
Mockito.when(A.getUriInfo()).thenReturn(uriInfo);
Mockito.when(A.getReq()).thenReturn(httpServletRequest);
```

You really don't need those two lines at all. In fact, you can remove the mock of `A` entirely (this line): `@Mock private A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);`

Instead, just do:

```
c.setUriInfo(uriInfo);
c.setReq(httpServletRequest);
```

This works because C extends A, meaning all of A's methods, when not overridden, are inherited by C. So if you call the non-overridden setter methods on the instance of C, it will go straight to the methods of A. After calling the set methods shown above, when you call `c.getUriInfo()`, it will return the object you passed in as a parameter to the `setUriInfo(uriInfo);` method. No need to mock at all here.

Comment: Apologies for confusion on Capital A .. have corrected in the code.

Comment: Remaining syntax errors aside, my answer is still correct. You don't need to mock calls to `a.getUriInfo()`, you can just call `c.setUriInfo(uriInfo)`, which will cause the correct object to be returned. This is due to java inheritance.